# How To Query A List Of Strings Using C#, Linq, and Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

Currently, I am trying to use the C# MongoDB Driver and Linq to return query results. I have the following JSON that I am trying to parse through:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "598b25038dcc43a92cdb24e3"
    },    
    "Skills": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Name": "test"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "Name": "test2"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "Name": "test3"
        }
    ]    
}
```

The function that I am trying to write takes in a list of strings as a parameter. The objective is to return a list of Mongo documents where one or more objects, in the Skills array, has a name equal to one or more strings passed in through the list.

I have come up with the following quick solution that used a bunch of embedded foreach loops but decided that wouldnt be the best route to go. I wanted to do something like the following with Linq:

```
            var query =
                from a in collection.AsQueryable<ApplicationUser>()
                where a.Skills.ForEach(applicantSkill => skills.Contains(applicantSkill.Name))
                select a;
            return query;
```

But this obviously throws an error. Could anyone point me in the right direction to querying using Linq/C# Mongo driver using a list of strings as params?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
collection.AsQueryable<ApplicationUser>()
.Where(user => 
    user.Skills
    .Select(s => s.Name)
    .Intersect(skills)
    .Any())
```